# OMNeT++/INET : Get specific logs of SimpleEpEnergy modules

Tags: omnet++, inet

Recently, I started making a wireless network on OMNeT++, by following [this tutorial](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/wireless/power/doc/index.html). The network is composed of multiple `AdhocHost` that communicate with each other.

```
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.AdhocHost;
import inet.physicallayer.wireless.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.canvas.integrated.IntegratedCanvasVisualizer;

network WirelessNetwork
{
    parameters:
        
    submodules:
        visualizer: IntegratedCanvasVisualizer {@display("p=100,100");}
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {@display("p=100,200");}
        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {@display("p=100,300");}
        host[3]: AdhocHost {@display("p=150,300");}
}
```

And the `ini` file :

```
[General]
network = WirelessNetwork
sim-time-limit = 100s

# visualizer
*.visualizer.energyStorageVisualizer.displayEnergyStorages = true
*.visualizer.AlternatingEpEnergyGenerator.isSleeping = true

# status
*.host[*].hasStatus = true

# power
*.host[*].energyStorage.typename = "SimpleEpEnergyStorage"
*.host[*].wlan[*].radio.energyConsumer.typename = "StateBasedEpEnergyConsumer"
*.host[*].energyManagement.typename = "SimpleEpEnergyManagement"
*.host[*].energyStorage.nominalCapacity = 0.05J
*.host[*].energyManagement.nodeShutdownCapacity = 0.1 * parent.energyStorage.nominalCapacity
*.host[*].energyManagement.nodeStartCapacity = 0.5 * parent.energyStorage.nominalCapacity
*.host[*].energyStorage.initialCapacity = uniform(0.1 * nominalCapacity, nominalCapacity)
*.host[*].energyGenerator.typename = "AlternatingEpEnergyGenerator"
*.host[*].energyGenerator.powerGeneration = 4mW
*.host[*].energyGenerator.sleepInterval = exponential(25s)
*.host[*].energyGenerator.generationInterval = exponential(25s)

# mobility
*.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
*.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
*.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
*.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMaxX = 1000m
*.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMaxY = 1000m
*.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m
*.host[*].mobility.initFromDisplayString = false
*.host[*].mobility.initialZ = 0m
*.host*.mobility.typename = "StationaryMobility"

# 802.11
*.host[*].wlan[*].bitrate = 54Mbps

# ping app
*.host[0].numApps = 0
*.host[*].numApps = 1
*.host[*].app[0].typename = "PingApp"
*.host[*].app[0].destAddr = "host[0]"
*.host[*].app[0].printPing = true
```

This code seems to work properly, but now I would like to get some specific logs of the `SimpleEpEnergy` modules, while hiding all other logs. I have no idea of how to manage this. Do I have to add some options in the `ini` file ? Or modify inet objects directly ?  My goal is to store information on these modules into a file (like `csv` or `txt`).

Answer (score 0):

You can filter over modules. Try something like that:

```
**.scalar-recording = false
**.vector-recording = false
**.statistic-recording = false
**.host[*].energy*.**.statistic-recording = true
**.host[*].energy*.**.scalar-recording = true
**.host[*].energy*.**.vector-recording = true
```

but since you need to export to csv, you may also record all available statistics (don't use the lines above) and then filter it in the resulting .anf file (double-click .vec or .sca file in result folder). To export then filtered entries to a csv file, just click "export data" button in .anf file menu (right corner, second button of a blue color).